# JavaScript Garbage Collection and Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection

I'm using a JavaScript OO pattern where I'm declaring classes via prototypes:

```
function MyClass(id) {
    this.id = id;
    ...
}

MyClass.prototype.doStuff = function(json) {
    ...
```

And I'm instantiating my class from other classes:

```
new MyClass();
```

Upon construction my class often binds jQuery event listeners to perform actions:

```
   this.$header = $('#myHeaderId');
   this.$header.on('click', $.proxy(MyClass.prototype.doStuff, this));
```

I'm assuming that if no JS variable holds a reference to my object then it is only the event bindings that are keeping it reachable. And if the HTML element that has the event bound to it is removed from the DOM (via jQuery's #remove, #empty etc), then my object is now unreachable and will be GCed?

Is that assumption correct?

Comment: I believe so yes. It would be worth double checking the jQuery source just to be sure though.

Comment: The event listeners are bound to the jQuery object. You can't get a reference to your object with that. Your object would be garbage collected if no variable references if.